# Why is my template helper that uses session.get not reactive?

Tags: javascript, meteor

In my client code I have a Session which is set to an object in a global function:

*somefunctions.js*

```
updateTimelineItem = function(newSelection){
    var selectedItem = $.grep(Session.get('liveProjectData').items,function(e){return e.position ==newSelection.parent().index()});
    Session.set('selectedItem',selectedItem[0]);
};
```

However, in a template file where I need to display portions of this session's object data, my helper does not fire after the session is set.

*mytemplate.js*

```
Template.mytemplate.helpers({    
    selectedItem: function(){
        console.log('reactive update. new item selected.');
        return Session.get('selectedItem');
    }
})
```

*Example of what the session stores*

```
Object { position: 0, type: "image", source: "imgur", source-url: "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u…", provider: "magic", animation: "puff", thumb: "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u…", fullsize: "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u…", duration: 1000 }
```

I have tried to find documentation regarding when a Session would not be reactive without much luck. I know the session is set because I can write Session.get('selectedItem') in a browser console and I get the expected output.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `Session` will serialize its inputs which often leads to unusual behavior when storing complex data. Can you give an example of what `selectedItem[0]` may look like?

Comment: Thank you David, I've put an example of the data I store in the session in my question.

Comment: you may want to `JSON.stringify`/`JSON.parse` your object before/after setting/getting the session variable as David suggested

Comment: I have tried setting the session now to a simple string and the reactive code still does not run. Is it possible that the template.helpers are only considered reactive computations if Session.set(...) occurs inside the same template code? I am calling set from a global function because multiple templates access it (since multiple parts of the UI can trigger this).

Comment: No, the set and get can be in different computations. That's part of the point of reactive programming in Meteor.

Comment: The only possible reason is that updateTimelineItem isn't executing, If session is changed it will be updated something is wrong with your code.

Comment: I figured it out. The reactive function 'selectedItem' only runs if I use the Session variable in spacebars. As soon as I actually display the data on in the UI I see the console output.

Comment: Open the javascript console of the browser and try setting manually the session variable. If that triggers the recomputation, then the function that sets the new value for your session variable is not being called properly

Comment: Hi @Luchux. See the second to last sentence in my question and my previous comment. Possible bug in Meteor unless someone can provide an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The reason my reactive code was not running is because I did not access the specific reactive variable in the spacebars of that template. Although Template.helpers is a reactive computation, it executes based on usage of reactive vars in the dom. This is unlike other reactive computations.

Information regarding this is hard to come by but it is hinted at in the Meteor documentation for [Template.currentData()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_currentdata) and its usage inside of helper.

The work I needed to do with the reactive variable was outside of the view and should therefore not be used in Template.helper but instead [template.autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun).